# findViewById no detecta los TabItem

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

estoy usando un TabLayout en un fragmento en Android (kotlin). El findViewById me funciona perfectamente con todos los elementos excepto con los dos TabItems.

Los tabItems són tabRecibidas y tabRealizadas, su TabLayout es tabVisitas.

Fragmento del XML con el TabLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabVisitas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/rojo"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabRippleColor="@color/claro"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabRealizadas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:text="Realizadas" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabRecibidas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recibidas" />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

El TabLayout si que funciona, pero los TabItem no, aunque el autocomplementar del Android Studio si que da la opcion de usarlos.

Como se puede ver, tienen el mismo nombre.

```
private lateinit var tabVisitas : TabLayout
private lateinit var tabRealizadas : TabItem
private lateinit var tabRecibidas : TabItem
...
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.visitas_fragment, container, false)
viewVisitas = root
...
tabVisitas = viewVisitas.findViewById(R.id.tabVisitas)
tabRealizadas = viewVisitas.findViewById(R.id.tabRealizadas)
tabRecibidas = viewVisitas.findViewById(R.id.tabRecibidas)
```

El error que da es:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: viewVisitas.findViewById(R.id.tabRealizadas) must not be null
    at com.dds.trobify.presentation.visitas.VisitasFragment.cargarControladores(VisitasFragment.kt:67)
    at com.dds.trobify.presentation.visitas.VisitasFragment.onCreateView(VisitasFragment.kt:46)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Lo que te respondieron en SO en inglés está correcto, postear acá la pregunta nuevamente no hace inválida la respuesta que recibiste: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331706/15298643

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:
> viewVisitas.findViewById(R.id.tabRealizadas) must not be null

El código indica que en el archivo `visitas_fragment.xml` debes tener el elemento con id `tabRealizadas`

```
private lateinit var tabRealizadas : TabItem
...
...
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.visitas_fragment, container, false)
viewVisitas = root
...
...
tabRealizadas = viewVisitas.findViewById(R.id.tabRealizadas)
```

si no existe el elemento con id `tabRealizadas` dentro del archivo `visitas_fragment.xml` esto estaría provocando el error.

Comment: el elemento si que existe, al final me he decantado por crear los TabItem mediante código.